# How to connect to a server that is not part of a domain from a computer that is on a domain

Tags: windows, networking

I have an AWS standalone server, that I have set up some local accounts on for users to access a file share.  All has been working fine with four users who are not on a domain.  I can map a shared drive to their computers.

However, I now have to connect two users who are using domain accounts.  I cannot work out the syntax to get them to connect to the file share.  I've tried a username in the format:

- .\USERNAME
- COMPUTERNAME\USERNAME (i.e WIN-XXXXXXXX\USERNAME)
- USERNAME

None of the above work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be DOMAINNAME\USERNAME or USERNAME@DOMAINNAME so if your domain is xxxxx.com try xxxxx\USERNAME or USERNAME@xxxxx and if that don't work type the whole domain like xxxxx.com\USERNAME or USERNAME@xxxxx.com